# How do I pass in a variable inside a HTML link which will then pre populate different parts of a fields in my Django model form

Tags: html, django, django-models, django-views, django-forms

Please bare with me as this is my first post on here and I may have made some formatting erros in the way the question is presented and someone might have already answered my question. But I just can't find the answer. Thank you very much for your help in advance.

So I have a Django project that shows a weekly calender with items that people will be working on. Next to each day on the calender there is a button to add items on to the list but i want to make that button dynamic so it only takes in the current date that it is being showed next to and only takes the user that it is being showed under. Then i want that link to prepopulate two fields of a scheduleCreationForm.

Please see below the view of the html page and the code for the html page
[view of html page](https://i.stack.imgur.com/NmDh9.png)

```
# html file
    <section class="section">  
        <div class="row">
            {% for profile in profiles %}
                <div class="col-6 col-md-12 col-lg-6">
                    <div class="card">
                        <div class="card-content">
                            <div class="card-body">
                                <h4 class="card-title">{{profile.name}}</h4>
                                {% for date in ldates %}
                                <div class="d-flex justify-content-between">
                                    <p>{{date}}</p>
                                    <a href="#" ><i class="bi bi-plus-circle"></i></a>
                                </div>
                                <hr style="margin-top: 0px; margin-bottom: 0px; padding-top: 0px; padding-bottom: 0px;">
                                <table class="table" id="table1">
                                    <tbody>
                                        {% for event in user_schedules %}
                                            {% if event.engineer == profile and event.date|date:"l, d F Y" == date %}
                                                <tr>
                                                    <td style="border-top: none; border-bottom: none;"><a href="#" class="btn btn-light">{{event.project.project_id}}</a></td>
                                                    <td style="border-top: none; border-bottom: none;"><a href="#" class="btn btn-light">{{event.project.address|slice:"40"}}</a></td>
                                                    <td style="border-top: none; border-bottom: none;"><a href="#" class="btn btn-info">{{event.start_time|time:"H:i"}} - {{event.end_time|time:"H:i"}}</a></td>
                                                    <td style="border-top: none; border-bottom: none;"><a href="{% url 'delete-schedule' event.id %}" class="btn icon btn-danger"><i class="bi bi-x"></i></a></td>
                                                </tr>
                                            {% endif %}
                                        {% endfor %}
                                    </tbody>
                                </table>
                                {% endfor %}
                            </div>
                        </div>
                    </div>
                </div>
            {% endfor %}   
        </div>
    </section>
```

I want to be able to add a url going to the form page for this model but i want the link to prepopulate certain fields of the form from the user and the date it has been clicked on. How do i pass these parameters and how do i make it interact with the form page to prepopulate only the fields correlated.

Below are my views, models, forms and url.py files as well as how the form looks rendered out.

```
# models.py file

class Schedule(models.Model):
    # This is for the main bulk of the actual table and will be on the projects page
    engineer = models.ForeignKey(Profile, blank=False, null=True, on_delete=models.SET_NULL)
    project = models.ForeignKey(Project, blank=False, null=True, on_delete=models.SET_NULL)
    start_time = models.TimeField(null=True, blank=False)
    end_time = models.TimeField(null=True, blank=False)
    date = models.DateField(null=True, blank=True)
    
    creation_date = models.DateField(auto_now_add=True)
    id = models.UUIDField(default=uuid.uuid4, unique=True, primary_key=True, editable=False)
```

```
# forms.py file

class ProjectWidget(s2forms.ModelSelect2Widget):
    search_fields = [
        'address__icontains',

    ]

class ScheduleForm(ModelForm):
    class Meta:
        model = Schedule
        fields = '__all__'
        labels = {
            'project': 'Project Address',
        }
        widgets = {
            'date': forms.widgets.DateInput(attrs={'type': 'date'}),
            'start_time': forms.widgets.DateInput(attrs={'type':'time'}),
            'end_time': forms.widgets.DateInput(attrs={'type':'time'}),
            'project': ProjectWidget,
        }

    def __init__(self, *args, **kwargs):
        super(ScheduleForm, self).__init__(*args, **kwargs)

        for name, field in self.fields.items():
            field.widget.attrs.update({'class':'form-control'})

        
        self.fields['engineer'].widget.attrs.update({'class':'form-select'})
```

```
# views.py file

@login_required(login_url="login")
def schedule(request, tdate):

    profiles = Profile.objects.exclude(include_in_calendar=False)

    # To get the dates
    dt = date.today()
    start = dt - timedelta(days=dt.weekday())
    end = start + timedelta(days=6)
    user_schedules = Schedule.objects.filter(date__range=[start,end])
    ldates = pd.date_range(start,end-timedelta(days=2),freq='d')
    ldates = ldates.strftime('%A, %d %B %Y')
    start = start.strftime('%d %B %Y')
    end = end.strftime('%d %B %Y')
    

    

    context = {'start': start, 'end': end, 'profiles': profiles, 'ldates':ldates, 'user_schedules': user_schedules}
    return render(request, 'schedule/schedule.html', context)

@login_required(login_url="login")
def createScheduleItem(request):
    form = ScheduleForm()

    if request.method == 'POST':
        form = ScheduleForm(request.POST)
        if form.is_valid():
            form.save()
            return redirect(redirectSchedule)
            
    context = {'form': form}
    return render(request, 'schedule/global_schedule_form.html', context)

@login_required(login_url="login")
def deleteSchedule(request, pk):

    event = Schedule.objects.get(id=pk)
    event.delete()
    return redirect(redirectSchedule)

@login_required(login_url="login")
def redirectSchedule(request):
    dt = date.today()
    return redirect(schedule, dt)
```

```
# urls.py file

urlpatterns = [
    path('', views.redirectSchedule, name='schedule'),
    path('date/<str:tdate>', views.schedule, name='date-schedule'),
    path('create-schedule-item', views.createScheduleItem, name='create-schedule-item'),
    path('delete-schedule/<str:pk>/', views.deleteSchedule, name='delete-schedule'),
]
```

This is how the create schedule form is rendered out.
[Rendered Schedule Form](https://i.stack.imgur.com/1V8Gg.png)

From the pictures i just want to be able to pass in to a paramter in the link in the plus button on the schedule page to be able to pre populate the two fields engineer and date depending on the date they click the plus next to and the engineer they've clicked it under.

The variables are dynamic in the html template so just need to know how to pass it in to the link and how to allow the form to receive the information to prepopulate the field.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

First create a new endpoint that accepts the additional fields, in this case the id of the engineer (e.g. 42) and the selected date as a string (e.g. 2023-03-28):

```
path('create-schedule-item', views.createScheduleItem, name='create-schedule-item'),
path('create-schedule-item/<int:engineer>/<str:date>/', views.createScheduleItem, name='create-schedule-item'),
```

Next add these optional parameters to the view function and pass them as [initial data](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/4.1/ref/forms/fields/#initial) to the form:

```
@login_required(login_url="login")
def createScheduleItem(request, engineer=None, date=None):
    initial = {}
    if engineer and date:
        initial = {
            'engineer': engineer,
            'date': date,
        }

    form = ScheduleForm(initial=initial)

    if request.method == 'POST':
        form = ScheduleForm(request.POST)
        if form.is_valid():
            form.save()
            return redirect(redirectSchedule)
            
    context = {'form': form}
    return render(request, 'schedule/global_schedule_form.html', context)
```

Finally use the new endpont with pre-populated data in the template:

```
<a href="{% url 'create-schedule-item' profile.id date %}"><i class="bi bi-plus-circle"></i></a>
```

This will create URLs like `/create-schedule-item/42/2023-03-28/`.